# Video background on a wordpress website not showing up properly on IE9

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, flash

Using JW player, i am trying to embed a  video as a website background. I am using Wordpress as CMS for the website. The home page works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox, but it does not show up properly on IE 9. I am having a hard time trying to figure what is wrong.

Url to the website: [Demo website](http://goo.gl/Uujdi)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the video doesn't cover the whole background on my resolution so set the width and height of the video element to:

```
video_wrapper{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Considering IE9 can you explain what is wrong or provide a screenshot?

Comment: Well i cleared my cache,restarted IE and it seems to be working as intended now.

The video used to appear before the content, not under the content as background.